Seneca's take on suicide
I stumbled on this article which discusses Seneca's view on suicide. I must admit, I'm a bit disappointed by Seneca's view on suicide, even though I am still a huge fan of Stoicism. While many Stoic maxims make sense to me, the idea of taking control over the timing and manner of one's death as a form of freedom is quite unsettling. It's not something I find as universally acceptable or wise as the other teachings. However, I understand that this is Seneca's personal take, not a general Stoic doctrine.
What do you all think about this perspective?

more broadly than the question, as part of studying philosophy, I would urge you to sit with this discomfort, because those points of discomfort are often points where you can grow your understanding philosophy. Like... try to understand where Seneca's arguments are coming from; if one accepts his premises, do they follow necessarily? or what other premises are they based on? And then separately, what are your objections to the conclusions? what premises would you need to reject to reject the conclusions?

There is a tenancy to try to paper over uncomfortable disagreements w/ our preferred philosophy or philosopher. e.g. "Oh, that was just Seneca's personal take, not broader Stoicism, so I can disregard it", or "Oh, xyz's misogyny was a product of his time, not integral to his philosophy". I think you do yourself a real service by thinking about it (as you are doing with this question) and regardless of how you resolve the disagreement I think you'll come away with a fuller understanding of stoicism, your own ethics, your thoughts on suicide, etc.

I’m voting to close this question because this site generally rejects "What do you think?" and rather aspires to short, fact-based questions and answers about canonical philosophy.

Few emotional struggles match the challenge of greeting one's death. Christianity has a doctrine built on the transcendence of life over death and promises eternal life. To a stoic, mastering one's relationship to one's inevitable death is a central concern. Death and euthanasia also plays prominently in other traditions, like the practice of seppuku. Here in Chicago, Kübler-Ross did some psychological research on the topic too in her book On Death and Dying.

He is really advocating euthanasia, rather than suicide. That is dying based on poor quality of life, rather than sorrow or disappointment or setbacks, and so on.
It is crucial to war that people be willing to die, and an army of people like that is crucial to gaining and holding rights and wellbeing that a minority or other states might wish to end or take. While we wish to dissuade people from impulsively committing suicide, losing themselves opportunities and making others sad, this is in tension with the fact all societies are built on some fraction of them knowing what they would be willing to die for. A Stoic's job is not to shy away from such tensions, but to contemplate the nature of our inevitable death.
Have you heard of the Death Cafe movement? Our unwillingness to think and talk about death, plus that many people lack encounters with it before facing their own, are important modern issues.

"Begin with the End in mind", eh?

+1 Interesting link to boot!
